# Azure java SDK - how to read events from an Event Hub?

Tags: java, azure

I have a Java app with the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
   <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
   <version>1.33.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I need to consume events from an Event Hub. I can't seem to find out how to this.

```java
Azure azure = Azure.configure().withLogLevel(...).authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(subscriptionId);
EventHub eventHub = azure.eventHubs().getByName("?", "?", "?");

//Now what?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at the [`docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/messaging-eventhubs-readme?view=azure-java-stable#consume-events-with-eventhubconsumerasyncclient)? . You need to create the Client

```
EventHubConsumerAsyncClient consumer = new EventHubClientBuilder()
    .connectionString("<< CONNECTION STRING FOR SPECIFIC EVENT HUB INSTANCE >>")
    .consumerGroup(EventHubClientBuilder.DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP_NAME)
    .buildAsyncConsumerClient();

// Receive newly added events from partition with id "0". EventPosition specifies the position
// within the Event Hub partition to begin consuming events.
consumer.receiveFromPartition("0", EventPosition.latest()).subscribe(event -> {
    // Process each event as it arrives.
});
```

and use the method getData();

```
EventData event = partitionEvent.getData();
```

Comment: So there are two different libraries? I mean, I have been using the one I mentioned for a while to manage VMs, I assumed I would be able to manage event hubs too.